# Ordering results in Doctrine by comparison statement

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm

**Summary: Can we do `ORDER BY parent_id = id DESC` in Doctrine?**

We have a database table `Category` which contains hierarchical article categories. The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `parent_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_FF3A7B97727ACA70` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;
```

The hierarchy is only one level deep and the top level is identified with their `parent_id` being the same as their `id`.

We'd like to fetch all the rows using the Doctrine QueryBuilder (DQL would do as well) so that all the categories are listed consecutively, the category's parent being the first and it's children following directly afterwards. Like this:

```
id  parent_id   sort    name
-----------------------------------
1   1           1       Animals
5   1           1       Cat
10  1           3       Dog
9   1           2       Walrus
2   2           2       Fruits
13  2           3       Apple
12  2           2       Pear
11  2           1       Melon
3   3           3       Vehicles
15  3           2       Car
6   3           3       Train
14  3           1       Paraglider
```

Using this native MySQL query we are able to get the items in the order we want:

```
select * from Category order by parent_id asc, parent_id = id desc;
```

However, we don't know how to do that in the QueryBuilder or DQL. The problem is the `parent_id = id` sort condition which results in an error in DQL: `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 109: Error: Expected end of string, got '='`

We have a workaround with `$em->createNativeQuery()` but we would really like to find a proper way to do this the ORM way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT *, CASE id WHEN parent_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS custom_order
FROM Category 
WHERE ORDER BY parent_id ASC, custom_order DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need all the rows in the order demonstrated in the question. The query works fine without `WHERE` and produces the results we want. We just want to do it without native MySQL queries.

Comment: Did you want to get all rows but rows whom id is equal to parent_id come first?

Comment: Yes, we need them primarily ordered by `parent_id` and secondarily on whether their `parent_id` is the same as their `id`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd need that translated to DQL. Using `CASE` results in a Doctrine error ("expected literal, got CASE").

Comment: Now i can't try the query with DQL but i think it will work with createNativeQuery() method.

Comment: Yes, but we're trying to get rid of `createNativeQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

My reputation doesn't allow me to comment on the answer from aykut but i just wanted to point out that i had the exact same problem as the topic-poster and the CASE statement solved it nicely.

Kaivosukeltaja reports that using a CASE results in a Doctrine error, but in my case :-) this didn't happen. It seems CaseExpressions have been added since version 2.2:
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/commit/816ce41f638d28934c79a12ef27f954124b2639e